# How to use gb4e to produce glossed example with bracket?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I would like to use the package gb4e to produce glossed example with bracket, but I don't know which part is incorrect.

```latex
\begin{exe}

\ex 

\gll \lb{ }Zhangsan zhidao \lb{ } Lisi taoyan ziji. ]]\\

           Zhangsan knows Lisi dislikes self. \\

\glt     `Zhangsan knows that Lisi dislikes himself.'

\end{exe}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to create something like '[Zhangsan zhidao [Lisi taoyan ziji]]'

Answer (score 6):

The `\ex` command assumes an optional argument for the grammaticality judgement, so your example needs to be enclosed in braces, otherwise the `[` will be treated as the grammaticality judgement.  There are two cases to consider:

For examples without a grammaticality judgement, it's sufficient to enclose the example sentence in braces, as in (1).

However, for examples that have a grammaticality judgement (even if empty), you will need to protect the opening `[` somehow for it to be displayed as shown in (2). This is a bit of a quirk of `gb4e` (some might say a bug).

There are various ways you can protect the initial `[` in examples with grammaticality judgements.  In (3) I've put braces around the bracket. In (4) I've added `\relax` before the bracket. In (5) because of the `\gll` command, no protection is needed (but the whole example sentence needs to be in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex{[This] is an example which displays properly.}
\ex[*]{[This] is an example which doesn't display properly.}
\ex[*]{{[}This] is an example which does display properly.}
\ex[*]{\relax[This] is an example that works too.}
\ex[*]{\gll [This] is a glossed example\\
            [This] is a glossed example\\}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]